# AnyLogic: How to calculate pedestrian traveled distance?

Tags: anylogic

Is there any specific way (except writing functions myself) to calculate traveled distance of a `ped` object in pedestrian library, something like `getDistanceDriven()` method in Road Traffic Library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing for it... start coding it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

there is only one way I can think of beyond coding it yourself: use the "Log model execution" functionality. Just click on the database on the project view and tick the box:

.
[image]

Then run your model and it will record the distance travelled for each agent in the dbase view "agent_movement_stats_log". Note that you can turn off any of the other logs you don't need...

[image]

Comment: Interesting point, and probably I'll use it in future, but for now, I need this data for specific `ped` chosen by user, and meantime I need a way to reach this value in my model both for calculations and display. Is there any form this log?

P.S. Although it seems self-coding it is much easier.

Comment: you cannot define which individual agents to log, only which class (in the class properties). You can reach the vaues with the normal SQL statements but I am not sure if the logs are updated continuously throughout the model or only at the end, you'd need to check that. But I agree: self-coding might be much easier.